# textarea value property ignore the linebreaks and whitespaces when read it with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I've been working on a small notebook app that works on the browser, my problem is that if i typed a note like this:

***hello**

***this is my first note***

the app show it like this:

**hello this is my first note**

I also want the elements with id's of `header` and `footer` to be shown even when i scroll down or up (sth like setting posiotion to fixed but this doesn't work for me).

**here is a link to the project to see the codes and try it. [Codepen](https://codepen.io/ayman-tarig/pen/Rvwqxv)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to replace linebreaks and whitespaces with html like

```
note.value.replace(/\n/g, '<br>\n').replace(/\s/g,'&nbsp;');
```

and add it to the `innerHTML` of the `<li>` instead of creating a textnode.

```
li.innerHTML = show;
```

Take a look at my example:

```js
const main = document.getElementById("main");
const add = document.getElementById("add"); //new note
const submit = document.getElementById("submit"); //submit the new note
const cancel = document.getElementById("cancel");
const screen = document.getElementById("screen");
const ul = document.getElementById("list");
const del = document.getElementById("delete");
const note = document.getElementById("note");
const back = document.getElementById("back");

let mynotes = {};
let i = 0;

add.addEventListener('click', function() {
  main.style.display = "block";
  submit.style.display = "inline";
  cancel.style.display = "inline";
  add.style.display = "none";
  screen.style.display = "none";
  del.style.display = "none";
  back.style.display = "none";
});

submit.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (note.value) {
    newNote = note.value.replace(/\n/g, '<br>\n').replace(/\s/g,'&nbsp;');
    if (newNote.length > 50) {
      show = newNote.substring(0, 46) + "...";
    } else {
      show = newNote;
    }

    if (mynotes.hasOwnProperty(show)) {
      show = show + `${++i}`;
    }

    mynotes[show] = newNote;

    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.setAttribute('class', 'item');
    li.innerHTML = show;
    ul.appendChild(li);
    note.value = "";
  } else {
    alert("can't add empty note");
  }

  main.style.display = "none";
  screen.style.display = "block";
  submit.style.display = "none";
  cancel.style.display = "none";
  add.style.display = "inline";
  del.style.display = "none";
  back.style.display = "none";
});

ul.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  node = event.target;
  item = event.target.innerHTML;
  text.innerHTML = mynotes[item];
  fullnote.style.display = "block";
  main.style.display = "none";
  submit.style.display = "none";
  add.style.display = "none";
  screen.style.display = "none";
  cancel.style.display = "none";
  del.style.display = "inline";
  back.style.display = "inline";
});

del.addEventListener('click', function() {
  ul.removeChild(node);
  delete mynotes[item];
  main.style.display = "none";
  screen.style.display = "block";
  submit.style.display = "none";
  add.style.display = "inline";
  fullnote.style.display = "none";
  back.style.display = "none";
  del.style.display = "none";
});

cancel.addEventListener('click', function() {
  note.value = "";
  main.style.display = "none";
  screen.style.display = "block";
  submit.style.display = "none";
  add.style.display = "inline";
  fullnote.style.display = "none";
  del.style.display = "none";
  back.style.display = "none";
  cancel.style.display = "none";
})

back.addEventListener('click', function() {
  main.style.display = "none";
  screen.style.display = "block";
  submit.style.display = "none";
  add.style.display = "inline";
  fullnote.style.display = "none";
  back.style.display = "none";
  del.style.display = "none";
});
```

```css
#container {
  background-color: rgb(253, 248, 177);
}

#header,
#footer {
  z-index: 2;
}

#title {
  color: white;
  padding-top: 7px;
}

#cancel,
#submit,
#back {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#add {
  font-size: 20px;
}

#delete,
#cancel,
#submit {
  display: none;
}

#main {
  display: none;
}

#note {
  resize: none;
}

#fullnote {
  display: none;
}

#back {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<div class="container min-vh-100 d-flex flex-column" id="container">

  <!-- header -->
  <div class="row align-items-start bg-info" id="header">
    <div class="col text-center">
      <button type="button" class="btn" id="cancel">&#10007;</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn" id="back">&#8617;</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col text-center">
      <h4 id="title">Notebook</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col text-center">
      <button type="button" class="btn" id="submit">&#10004;</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <br />

  <!-- Screen list show -->
  <div class="row" id="screen">
    <div class="col-12">
      <ul id="list">

      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Note show -->
  <div class="row" id="fullnote">
    <div class="col-12">
      <p id="text">
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>


  <!-- textarea -->
  <div class="row flex-grow-1">
    <div class="col" id="main">
      <textarea class="form-control textarea h-100" value="" placeholder="write note" id="note"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>


  <!-- footer -->
  <div class="row align-items-end" id="footer">
    <div class="col d-flex justify-content-start" style="padding: 10px; padding-left: 25px;">
      <button id="add" class="btn btn-info rounded-circle"><h4 style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">&#x2b;</h4></button>
      <button id="delete" class="btn btn-info rounded-circle">&#128465;</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: it works now, but if you try to use the app and click on the note after you create it, it will show you just an empty screen.

Comment: edited my codesnippet, you have to set your preview from textContent to innerHTML, too.

Answer (score 0):

You either have to convert the newlines to br's:

```
str = str.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br>');
```

Or you can do this with css:

```
.text, .item {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```